# Prevent dns name automatically changed to IP Address in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dns, centos7

I have apache tomcat 7 web server in linux centos 7, with standard installation. the network administrator has already set the dns name to access my web application for example : http://example.com/MyApps

the problem is, when i typed the url address for example http://example.com/MyApps
the web is showing, but the url automatically changes to ip address something like this http://210.211.XXX.XXX:1236/MyApps

how this can be happen?please help.

Comment: in case the address changes in the browser: your app replies with a http redirect to that ip address

Comment: Try setting ProxyPreserveHost ON in the proxy_mod .. I remember having this issue long time back

Comment: Are you using a proxy? If so, what and how?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no, i'm not using proxy

Comment: Tomcat doesn't usually rewrite URLs for clients. Are you using your own application, or some example/test application? The first URL you jave in your question will be served by a process listening on port `80`, and the second URL clearly uses port `1236`. What is listening on port `80`?